# Redis Lettuce: Transaction with different codecs

Tags: redis, lettuce

I'm working with Lettuce (the Java Redis Client) and I need to update several keys within one transaction, some of which are Strings and some are ByteArrays.

Without transactions, I'm just using `RedisClient.connect()` for the String keys and `RedisClient.connect(ByteArrayCodec.INSTANCE)` for the ByteArray keys. However, when I want to use transactions I can only use one of them, so I can't create a transaction where I can update both key types.

MWE:

```java
RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create("...");
RedisCommands<String, String> stringCommands = redisClient.connect().sync();
RedisCommands<byte[], byte[]> byteArrayCommands = redisClient.connect(ByteArrayCodec.INSTANCE).sync();

stringCommands.multi();
byteArrayCommands.multi();
stringCommands.set("Hello", "World");
byteArrayCommands.set("Hello2".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "World2".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        
// I would need one exec here, otherwise there is some period of time where the string keys are updated,
// but the byte array keys are not (or the other way round)
stringCommands.exec();
byteArrayCommands.exec();
```

Is there a dedicated way to deal with this problem in Lettuce? <s>I can obviously write my own codecs implementation which somehow combines String and ByteArray, but that seems somwhat cumbersome.</s> I tried to write my own codes implementation to combine the two cases, but that does not seem to be trivial, since I don't know what kind of key I have in the `decodeValue` function.

Also, I have no influence on the Redis instance, so I can't change how keys are stored.

Comment: For anyone having the same question, there is also a respective [issue in Github](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/issues/2608)